# Dynamically add Applicationbar in Application.Resources

Tags: windows-phone-8, application-bar, application-resource

Could anybody tell me how to do the following dynamically. I have refered many sites. but nothing helped me.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="DefaultAppBar" IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="mnuAdd" IconUri="/icons/appbar.add.rest.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="Add" Click="mnuAdd_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="SingleSelectionAppBar" IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="mnuPin" IconUri="/icons/appbar.pushpin.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="Pin" Click="mnuPin_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="mnuDelete" IconUri="/icons/appbar.delete.rest.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="Delete" Click="mnuDelete_Click"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="mnuEdit" IconUri="/icons/appbar.edit.rest.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="Edit" Click="mnuEdit_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="MultiSelectionAppBar" IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="mnuDeleteMulti" IconUri="/icons/appbar.delete.rest.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="Delete" Click="mnuDelete_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

We can `get the resource dynamically` as below. but **how to add at runtine**

```
ApplicationBar = (Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar)Resources["SingleSelectionAppBar"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution but i did not searched well. Anyway adding solution here

**Syntax:**

```
Application.Current.Resources.Add (name, value)
```

**Sample**

```
Application.Current.Resources.Add("DefaultAppBar", AppBar1);

Application.Current.Resources.Add("SingleSelectionAppBar", AppBar2);

Application.Current.Resources.Add("MultiSelectionAppBar", AppBar3);
```